# Can cufon style form text input and textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, cufon

Is it possible to do this?  I haven't been able to find anything in the documenation that says you CAN'T do it, but the following selector is not working for me:

```
Cufon.set('fontFamily', 'Museo');
Cufon.set('fontWeight', '300');
Cufon.replace('input.text, input.password, textarea');
```

Any ideas, or does Cufon simply not support this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would strongly advise against it.  You would end up introducing tons of usability issues in your site (i.e. no copy/paste and backspace issues).  Cufon has it's place in this world, but not on dynamically user edited text.

You would also introduce alot of "jump" behavior into your site since Cufon's JavaScript blocks in the browser until it has all of the required text replaced.  This would break the flow of content up in your site.